# Persisting Data from one controller to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hey guys,
What is the best mechansims for persisting viewmodel data from one controller to another.

For instance

return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController");

I need to have some data from the previous controller available to the new controller I am redirecting to.

Comment: TempData looks like a bad choice and uses sessions. So that is a no.

Comment: What type is the data you want to persist?

Comment: @Rory mainly string goo, nothing heavy

Comment: My ViewModel is [Serializable] as well and I an using SQL Server to store session state. However I don't like using sessions.

Comment: I thoght about throwing it in the RouteValue Dictionary however I was reading that is a bad idea if you have more than a few values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not  passing an object or something complex, make use of parameters. Just make sure redirected action gets parameters to display what it should.

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController",new { id=someString} );
```

Get the parameter in the action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string id)
{
    //do something with it
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I was going to do that, however it did not look like a very elegant way of doing things. However; if this is how folks are doing it then I might as well follow suit.

Comment: It is nicely explicit, and you can catch any errors (missing parameters etc.) at compile time.

Comment: What's wrong with it? It's simple. You do not want to look for fancy things for simple tasks.

Answer (score 1):

@Ufuk Hacıoğulları: You can't share information between 2 controllers using ViewData. ViewData only shares information between Controller and View.

If you need to share complex information between multiple Controllers while redirection, use "TempData" instead.

Here is how you use "TempData" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is going to send an http response to the client that directs it to then make a new http request to `/SomeController/SomeAction`. An alternative would be for you to call a method on your other controller directly... `new SomeController().SomeAction(someData)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpfull to you to pass value from one action to another action .

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string ToUserId)
        {
            ViewBag.ToUserId = ToUserId;
            return View();

        }


 public ActionResult ssss(string ToUserId)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = @ToUserId });
        }
```